# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code -> (xcode 15.1- React native)

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, xcode15

[image]

here is Pods-exampleApp-frameworks.sh file under Pods->Targert support files-> Pods-exampleApp

I tried
upgrading cocoapods to latest version
& fresh pods installation.
Cleaned derived data folder

React-native version - 0.68.5
Xcode version - 15.1